# CSS3 Gradient not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

For some reason my CSS Gradient isn't working in Firefox (v10.0.1). The main background for the page is supposed to be a gradient from white at the top down to a blueish colour, but in Firefox instead of a smooth gradient I'm just getting two solid blocks of colour, one white, one blue. In Chrome and Safari (on iPad & iPhone) it works perfectly.

Here is the test url for the page:

http://testing.xenongroupadmin.com/bitesize/login.html

And here is my CSS code:

```
body  { font-family: arial, tahoma, verdana, sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 42%, #CDEDFA 6%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 42%, #CDEDFA 6%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 42%, #CDEDFA 6%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 42%, #CDEDFA 6%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 42%, #CDEDFA 6%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
                    linear,
                    left bottom,
                    left top,
                    color-stop(0.42, #FFFFFF),
                    color-stop(0.06, #CDEDFA));


    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:1350px;
        }
```

I've tried searching for an answer but can't seem to find an example which matches my current predicament.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this... its cross browser even works in ie6

```
.bodyGradient {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    border-top: 3px solid #93ae59; 
    z-index: -1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cfddac,  #fff);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cfddac), to(#fff));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cfddac', endColorstr='#ffffff');
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(207,221,172),rgb(255,255,255));
}
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, and I love that it works in IE as well - I'd sort of written off using gradients in IE! One question though - how can I shift the gradient further down the page, so that there is more white on the page and the blue starts to fade in towards the bottom?

Comment: i dont know the exact solution for that but you can put another div over it with solid color, and gradient div under it..

Comment: if it worked for you.. so you wont mind marking it as correct answer

Comment: You can modify the start position of the gradient - replace 'top' in the gradient declarations to be '25%' to start 1/4 way down the page. Unfortunately I don't think you can do that in the ie filter.

Comment: That sort of worked, apart from the gradient goes from left to right instead of top to bottom - any ideas for how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

use "background-image" instead of "background", like this example from http://gradients.glrzad.com/
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #DBA803 13%, #FFCA1D 57%, #FFF338 79%);

Answer (score 0):

write this in your `css`

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top , #FFFFFF 62%, #CDEDFA 89%);
```

Better way to define `gradient` for all browsers

```
body  { 
    background: linear-gradient(top , #FFFFFF 62%, #CDEDFA 89%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top , #FFFFFF 62%, #CDEDFA 89%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , #FFFFFF 62%, #CDEDFA 89%);
        }
```